# What can be the possible reasons for the object code of an unchanged C++ file to change on recompilation?

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, operating-system

It's not really my question. It's a dormant question I found on quora. One answer was that some of the header files might have changed but the author of the questions claims they did not. I would love to hear what people here have to say :)

Comment: Are you also assuming that the compiler is invoked with the same options (including optimization levels)?

Comment: The timestamp, for a start. There was actually an Australian patent claim some years ago concerning a method or means to make the compiler produce bitwise-identical object code by manipulation of the system time. I argued strenuously against it, on the grounds of obviousness and prior art, as I was doing exactly that in the 1970s.

Answer (score 9):

- Changed header files
- Different compiler
- Different command line options
- Timestamp in object code
- Nondeterministic code generator or optimizer
- Profile-driven optimization with changed profile
- Nondeterminism induced by changes in OS provided services

Comment: Note that "changed header files" includes any header files that the code uses, not just the ones that are part of that the project.

Comment: Add different compiler version.

Comment: @starbolin: That's a special case of bullet #2.

Comment: Note that nondeterministic code generator is more likely that one could think. As soon as you start having collection of pointers to objects and order/hash the pointer values, you get a non-deterministic order in that collection; if you iterate directly over it (without sorting) to lay out code blocks...

Comment: @MatthieuM. Interesting point.  The OS can cause the compiler to do different things by providing storage allocation ("GetSpace") that produces different answers.  But there are stranger causes: e.g., ASLR changes the starting location of the stack for a thread; now we already have addresses (in the stack) that are different.  Other sources might be as OS-provided buffer address that varies due to storage demand on the kernal of a recent (or not) interrupt.

Answer (score 1):

You don't mention the platform, but if it's .NET, then it could be for similar reasons to what happens in the C# compiler as described by Eric Lippert here: http://ericlippert.com/2012/05/31/past-performance-is-no-guarantee-of-future-results/

Comment: I especially like the one "depends on order in which files are placed in directories", because this is pretty much invisible to people.